# AS statement changing result of SQL query in SELF JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, popsql

I'm running a SELF JOIN query and realized that if I use AS statement to rename the column names this is changing the final result of the query.

The result "using AS" is the correct answer and "without AS". According to my understanding, AS should only change the re-naming of the columns.

With AS (correct answer)

[ibb.co/tZqDL1M](https://ibb.co/tZqDL1M)

Without AS (incorrect answer)

[ibb.co/dJswj6H](https://ibb.co/dJswj6H)

Notice how in the "without AS" case the JOIN does not appear to work correctly.
Can anybody explain this?

Comment: That looks like a bug in the tool you are using to run the SQL queries.  Sad, really.

Comment: you definitely need aliases on the table names, but i didnt think youd need them on the column names.  Probably a bug like @GordonLinoff said

Comment: Wow, really disappointing. I need to learn to run this on MySQL bash. Do you think its a PopSQL bug? Would this work on MySQL bash?

Comment: @KamboMambo . . . I have never seen this in a GUI database tool, so I assume that most are safe.  There are situations where it occurs in a subquery where the columns are the same . . . I am guessing that the tool is re-expressing the query using a subquery for some reason.

Comment: Thanks so much to everybody. Such a shame. I will send an email to PopSQL to get this fixed since its a dissapointment.